# How can you modify navigator in webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can you disable the navigator property of webdriver?

I have seen this code snippet used but it does not work for me for some reason:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})");
```

Since the porperty `webdriver: true` in `console.log(netdriver)`.